# Identify remote windows server from shell script

Tags: shell-script, windows

I need a way to Identify a windows SBS server, I have a script that mounts a file share on a SBS server, I need the script to positivity identify the server before mounting. It doesn't need to be secure,

My setup is like this :

My machine is on 192.168.5.17, the server is on 192.168.0.3, Because were on different subnets I cannot simply check the arp table for the machines mac address.

running Nmap against the server reveals these open ports

```
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-08-01 09:01 BST
Nmap scan report for host.somewhere.local (192.168.0.3)
Host is up (0.12s latency).
Not shown: 979 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
80/tcp    open  http
119/tcp   open  nntp
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
443/tcp   open  https
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
563/tcp   open  snews
1025/tcp  open  NFS-or-IIS
2002/tcp  open  globe
2301/tcp  open  compaqdiag
2381/tcp  open  compaq-https
2910/tcp  open  tdaccess
3389/tcp  open  ms-wbt-server
4443/tcp  open  pharos
6129/tcp  open  unknown
8192/tcp  open  sophos
8193/tcp  open  sophos
8194/tcp  open  sophos
9000/tcp  open  cslistener
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 20.70 seconds
```

The Nmap results show

> Nmap scan report for host.somewhere.local (192.168.0.3)

How did it reslove the name i've tried dig and host but cannot get the name from the IP

The machine runs https can I somwhow check the cert from a bash script? Or is their another way to check the host is actually who I expect it to be?

Thanks.

Comment: "_I need the script to positively identify the server before mounting. It doesn't need to be secure._" Isn't that rather a tautology?

Comment: @roaima thanks I don't know what 6 year ago me was asking for. However my life turned out fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

Verifying the https-certificate is propably the best idea. IP, MAC and Names can be easyly spoofed.

Look at `curl` to check https. You need to provide it with the public CA-certificate, too. As far as I remember the default is that it will deny download if the server-certificate does not match the CA.